# EL wire inverter to molex inside computer

Tags: inverter

I am trying to rig some EL tape into my computer, but I am unsure where to go at this point. So far, I know that I'm buying this inverter
http://www.adafruit.com/products/448?gclid=CPSI1IOS-b8CFZTm7Aodj1IAAQ 
As well as the EL tape, and it would now take 12 volt DC. But I don't know where to go from here. The inverter just has a + and -, and I know I'll be soldering it, but I don't know what it is soldered to. Should I just get a molex to molex and cut off one end?
Sorry I couldn't add more relevant tags, I'm new.

Edit-I was essentially asking what else should I get to wire it to molex, of that would work. The answer below is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for something like this:

[image]

Sorry for the image, I could not find anything better. And yes, that's from ebay.

This kind of adapter is great because you can put it anywhere without reducing the number of available connectors. Just cut away the fan connector and solder your EL inverter there.

**warning** The +12V line is the *yellow* wire. Usually fans run on +12V so that should not be a problem, however the connector in the picture seem to run from the +5V, I'm not sure though. Just be careful since you can find connectors that power the fan through the +5, the +12 and even between the +12 and the +5, to get 7V and run it quieter.

Comment: Look at the far left. The thin red/black pair is connecting to the same pins as the _yellow_ and black wires in the male molex.